# how to make GNOME Dialog boxes

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-shell, dialog

So I have played around with Zenity on a few Linux distros, but I haven't ever been able to achieve this effect:
[image]
So My question is, how do I create one of these dialog boxes?  I would like to have customizable title, body, and buttons.  I am on Fedora 35, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `zenity`, I've used `yad` for a number of years.  You can play around with fonts and colours if that is your thing.  One nice touch is that you can build a number of boxes of various types into a tabbed "notebook" or a paned display.

Comment: Yad is very close to what I want however, it does not do a number of the things built in to the GNOME desktop environment.